# How to use $mathTool in Polarion Live Report pages

Tags: velocity, polarion

Trying to re-use a script from a Polarion wiki page, I struggle to get $mathTool to work.

On the wiki page it was `#set($ratio= $mathTool.div($countIn, $countOut))` and it worked like a charm.

On the LiveReport page it looks like $mathTool doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Contacting their technical support reveals that `$mathTool` from wiki pages is available as `$math` in LiveReport pages ...